# Ruby on rails: get data only from the range of two column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to make appointment system where the user only can make appointment when it's available.I have 4 different tables:

1. Doctors table,
2. docdays table with references to doctor,
3. doctimes table with references to docdays.
4. booking table

**doctimes table: where the doctors store their schedule**

| start_time | end_time | docday_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 08:00:00 | 12:00:00 | 1 |
| 13:00:00 | 15:00:00 | 1 |

**booking table: where the patient can make appointment when the doctor is on schedule**

| start_time | end_time | doctor_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |

The patient will inputting their appointment data like `start_time` and `end_time` and it will be stored to booking table.

The thing is, how to only show the data between `start_time` and `end_time` on **doctimes table** so I could doing the validation?

I have tried it like this:

```
time_check = Doctor.select('doctors.id,doctimes.start_time,doctimes.end_time').
joins(:docday =>[:doctime]).where('doctimes.start_time BETWEEN ? AND ?', params[:start_time],params[:end_time]).where(id: params[:doctor_id])
```

But it seems for example with the current data, when patient tried to: input  `09:00:00` - `11:00:00` it will show nothing. because `08:00:00` is not between `09:00:00` - `11:00:00`
and what im doing is wrong, It should show the data, because `09:00:00` - `11:00:00` is still between `08:00:00` - `12:00:00`

Is there a way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

With your query, you are checking if `start_time` 8 is between 9 and 11, which is false.

What you have to test is that start_time 8 is less than 11 (so it's not after the range) and end_time 12 is more than 9 (so it's not before the range), that way you know the two ranges overlap.

```rb
.where('doctimes.start_time < ? AND doctimes.end_time > AND ?', params[:end_time], params[:start_time])
```

Comment: with your query when i inputed 7 and 9, it'll show data , eventhough it is not in the range of *doctime* `start_time` and `end_time`. and that is not what i want